# How to array item from left or right based on the value that input in typescript

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask how to remove an item to the left/right? for example the array is
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'] then the value is 'three'.
data.findIndex(x => x === value); then how to remove the 'four' or 'two'?

How to remove the item to the left or right?

for example I have an array which is `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']` then I have a value which is the `three`. then I try to find the index of `three`.
code:

```
data.findIndex(x => x === value)
```

then I get the index of `three` which is `2`.

How to remove the value `four` or `two`?

for example I just need to remove the next item which is the `four`

the output should be like this `['one', 'two', 'three', 'five']`.

it should be dynamic. cause when I try to change the value to `two` then the value should be remove it the `three` or `one`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one or subtract one from the found index?

```js
const data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
const index = data.findIndex(x => x === 'three');
data.splice(index + 1, 1);
console.log(data);
```

or create a new array

```js
const data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
const index = data.findIndex(x => x === 'three');
const result = data.filter((_, i) => i !== index + 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

var arr = { "one", "two", "three" }

arr.shift() -> takes away the first element of the array.
arr.pop()   -> takes away the last  element of the array.

If you want to get these elements while removing them you can do it simply:

var a = arr.shift() -> takes away the first element of the array and returns the element.
var p = arr.pop()   -> takes away the last  element of the array and returns the element.